# Opening dropdown menu from navbar branding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to open a dropdown menu (using Twitter Bootstrap) everytime I click on the brand of my navbar, so I tried this code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="tabbable">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a id="drop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu">
        <div class="brand">Brand</div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Item</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Result**: when I click on it, the menu appears, but it's *over* the brand, not *under*. How to fix it?

### Examples

- Standard version [OK]: http://jsfiddle.net/4rdPU/2/
- Standard version + `div class="brand"` [Style problem]: http://jsfiddle.net/4rdPU/1/
- Brand version [Wrong menu position]: http://jsfiddle.net/4rdPU/3/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To properly render the dropdown, your brand must be a `.nav li` element. So just add the `.brand` class to a standard dropdown.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="tabbable">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a id="drop1" class="dropdown-toggle brand" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu">
                        Brand
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Item</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That will break your brand positioning, but you fan fix it with this simple CSS:

```
.navbar .brand {
    margin-left: 10px; /* This value could be different for another layout */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you know why it adds some space on the left?

Comment: It seems that `margin-left: -15px;` is better :) It makes the text aligned like a normal brand, but when you press it is not so nice (there's only 5px on the left margin): I should try others values :)

Comment: It doesn't add, it subtracts. That's because you often will put the `.brand` inside a `.container`, wich has `padding: 20px` by default.

Comment: I used this jsfiddle, I hope it will help you finding the magic value ;) http://jsfiddle.net/simbirsk/4rdPU/5/

Comment: It seems that `margin-left: -20px; text-indent: 5px` aligns the text perfectly and when you press it there's no space left. Thank you :)

Comment: `margin-left: -20px; padding-left: 20px !important; padding-right: 20px !important;` seems to give the best result

Comment: OMG, this is getting a bit confusing. Have you checked my jsfiddle? Wasn't that the expected layout? Maybe there's some other element interfering and we can find a simple solution...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16423/discussion-between-francesco-frassinelli-and-simbirsk)